# Delphi: Setting varchar field to null through a query parameter

Tags: sql-server, delphi, bde

I've had a recent issue at work that I haven't been able to work out.  There is a snippet of code that was developed in Delphi 7 and recently migrated to 10.1.  The problem is that if there is no data to post we want to set a varchar field to null.

As it is we are using

```
ParamByName(strVar).DataType := ftString;
ParamByName(strVar).Clear;
ParamByName(strVar).Bound := true;
```

This used to set the field to NULL, but now it seems to be setting the field to an empty string.  Is there a change in behavior or is something amiss with our approach?

Comment: What components are you using for data access? It's not ADO, based on the code you posted.

Comment: Ken is right, your problem is in the data access driver. Please specify. Also find something like `SetEmptyStrToNull` in data driver parameters.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify, this is old BDE type access using components in Data.DB

Comment: Perhaps you encounter this bug in 10.1 regarding params and BDE: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16724

Comment: Its seems that bug did affect our code, will update with our fix